# How to change Date Format in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I have 2 date type in one of python dataframe column, i want to all the data values into same format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-06-01', '2016-06-01 10:00']})
print (df)
           Date
0        2016-06-01
1  2016-06-01 10:00
```

I want both the date in same format as below.

```
          Date
0  2016-06-01 00:00
1  2016-06-01 10:00
```

how to handle it using python.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2016-06-01', '2016-06-01 10:00']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
print (df)
                 Date
0 2016-06-01 00:00:00
1 2016-06-01 10:00:00
```

Comment: I hope my answer will be accepted, because I was first, but it is up to you. Thanks for upvote.Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for that:

```
In [3]: pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
Out[3]:
0   2016-06-01 00:00:00
1   2016-06-01 10:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And then if you want to show only hours and minutes you could use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) from `dt` accessor:

```
In [10]: pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Out[10]:
0    2016-06-01 00:00
1    2016-06-01 10:00
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: `40` seconds between posts. ;)

Comment: @jezrael yes, you're faster. And your post just after 68 seconds after OP.

Comment: thanks to Both of you for quick reply with right answer.